# Convert Dataset of Json lines to Dataframe with SparkSession

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset

I'm following the advice at https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/dealing_with_bad_data.html to clean some json data.

However the guide is outdated and I would like to use `sparkSession` to load the dataset and parse the json.

```
spark.read.text('file.json').as[String].map(x => parse_json(x))
```

So I ended up with a `Dataset[String]` instead of `RDD[String]`,
how do I read the lines of json in the dataset?

Comment: Try 

    spark.read.text('file.json').map(x => parse_json(x)).rdd

Comment: @Pushkr yes, works

Answer (score 0):

Define a case class (similar to java pojo) with the expected structure and map the input data to it.  Columns are automatically lined up by name, and the types are preserved. consider person.json as

```
{"name": "Narsireddy", "age": 30, "technology": "hadoop"}
```

the define case class like 
case class Person(name: String, age: Integer, technology: String) . Read json file and map to dataset of persons

```
val personDataSet = sqlContext.read.json("/person.json").as[Person]
```